# Accessing props in Jest/React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

I am testing a component `DisplayContent`

```
test('display component must have a male heading', () => {
    render(<DisplayContent />)
    const element = screen.getByText('Male')
    expect(element).toBeInTheDocument()
})
```

And here is my `Display` component

```
const DisplayContent = ({ fetchedData, filteredData, showSolution }) => {
   return ...
}
```

This is my function that is giving the errors

```
export const myFunction = (array, gender) => {
    let temp = []

    const genderArray = array.filter(el => el.gender === gender)

    genderArray.forEach(el => {
        el.obj.forEach(o => {
            if (o.type === 'Human') temp.push(o)
        })
    })

    return temp
}
```

However, if I run my test, I get an error saying  `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')`. I think this is because my `Display` component accepts 3 props. But in the testing file, I am only doing `render(<DisplayContent />)` and not passing any prop. But how can I pass props to it, as `fetchedData, filteredData, showSolution` are simply passed down from `App.js`, not exported from somewhere

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the props expected by the component when rendering it:

```
test('display component must have a male heading', () => {
    render(<DisplayContent fetchedData={[]} filteredData={[]} showSolution={() => {}}/>)
    const element = screen.getByText('Male')
    expect(element).toBeInTheDocument()
})
```